# how to not display an icon based on the props value using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to display an icon based on the props value using react and typescript.

what i am trying to do?
I have an ContainerComponent that uses ContentComponent which displays an icon. This ContentComponent is a reusable component.

Below is my ContainerComponent

```
render = () => {
    const value = 10;
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <LeftSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    <ContentComponent>
                        value=10
                        icon_name='add'
                    </ContentComponent>
                </ContainerComponent>
            </LeftSide>
            <RightSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    <ContentComponent>
                        value=10
                        icon_name='delete'
                    </ContentComponent>
                </ContainerComponent>
            </RightSide>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

ContentComponent renders the Icon and it looks like below,

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    icon_name,
    value,
}) => {
    return (
        <Icon name={icon_name}/>
    )
}
```

this icon component displays icons add and delete. now the question is i want to display the add icon only if the value is greater than 0.

How can i add the condition to ContentComponent such that add icon is rendered only when value is greater than 0.

**Note:** the container and content component will have someother elements to be rendered for sure..Just the Icon within ContentComponent needs to be displayed or not based on value and name being "add"...Icon with name "delete" will be displayed always no matter what the value is.

Could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just simply return null if the value is less than 1.

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    icon_name,
    value,
}) => {
    if(value<1 && icon_name=='add')
        return null
    return (
          <Icon name={icon_name}/>
    )
}
```

Since you are not using the `value` in `ContentComponent` you can do the check in the parent component like this:

```
render = () => {
    const value = 10;
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <LeftSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    {value>0 && <ContentComponent icon_name='add'/>}
                </ContainerComponent>
            </LeftSide>
            <RightSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    <ContentComponent icon_name='delete'/>
                </ContainerComponent>
            </RightSide>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks but this Icon can also be delete...i want to render it always irrespective of value.

Comment: thanks. i have edited the question (under note section) to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline if (`&&`) within JSX to render things conditionally by wrapping it with brackets:

```
return (
    <Wrapper>
        {value > 0 &&
            <LeftSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    <ContentComponent>
                        value=10 icon_name='add'
                    </ContentComponent>
                </ContainerComponent>
            </LeftSide>
        }
        <RightSide>
            <ContainerComponent>
                <ContentComponent>
                    value=10 icon_name='delete'
                </ContentComponent>
            </ContainerComponent>
        </RightSide>
    </Wrapper>
)
```

You may also remove the `value` prop from your Icon if it does not need to be aware of this variable.

Comment: thanks but there is other content to be rendered for sure within container and content components.

Comment: Then you should add this part to your question, answers will vary on the context you give

Comment: I have added this to the question now.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two icons, no need to pass `icon_name` in props.

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    value,
}) => {
    return (
        <>{ 
            value > 0 ? <Icon name="delete" /> : <Icon name="add" />
          }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i want to render delete icon always and add icon to be rendered based on value. As seen from my code...within leftside i have to display add button and right side delete button. but the contentComponent  has icon name and is reusabel for both add and delete. Now what i want to achieve is this add icon to be displayed only value > 0